# MediaPlayer doesn't play files named with DateTime

Tags: android, datetime, android-mediaplayer

For some reason Media Player doesn't play file if the date format is like that:

```
String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy  hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

Or:

```
Date date = new Date();
String dateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
```

Everything is going fine when the format is like that:

```
String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy  hh-mm-ss aa", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

Does somebody know why  and if I can do something with that, because I really prefer hh:mm:ss rather than hh-mm-ss ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for liking `-` over `:`. Would `.` be a suitable replacement?

Comment: The reason is this is how it is customary to write time, with ":".

Comment: Its not customary to put any of the following characters `\ / : * ? " < > |` in a file name, and is invalid in windows.

Comment: Understood, its just i tought it will be easier for users to understand

Comment: I agree with where you are coming from. using `-` in both date and time may cause confusion. I would consider trying `.` and see if it helps readability. Otherwise, see how you get on with `-`

Answer (score 0):

you should try to append `file://` in your path because I think Media Player cannot access your file.